# Do warnings slow down execution in R?

Tags: r, performance, io

I'm running code in R studio.  When my script finishes running, I get the orange message `There were 50 or more warnings (use warnings() to see the first 50)` at the bottom of my result (and in practice, I suspect the number of warnings is in the tens of thousands, at a minimum).  Are these warnings slowing down my code because they're I/O operations and therefore expensive?  I'm not seeing any error messages, but I'm not sure if the way R studio handles them, if they're still I/O operations, or if whatever way it's handling them deals with the slowdown I would normally expect such a large number of I/O operations to cause.

Comment: Usually best to deal with them, with `options(warn = 2)` warnings become errors.

Comment: Yeah, no way to deal with them apart from reimplementing the function to not throw warnings.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Generally, the answer will be yes, code that generates a lot of warnings will have some negative impact on performance although whether this impact is meaningful is going to vary. To illustrate:

```
library(bench)

v <- -1000:1000

res <- mark(no_warnings = sapply(abs(v), log),
            avoid_warnings = sapply(v, \(x) if (x < 0) NaN else log(x)),
            warnings = sapply(v, log), check = FALSE)

There were 50 or more warnings (use warnings() to see the first 50)
```

Results:

```
# A tibble: 3 × 13
  expression          min  median `itr/sec` mem_alloc `gc/sec` n_itr  n_gc total_time
  <bch:expr>     <bch:tm> <bch:t>     <dbl> <bch:byt>    <dbl> <int> <dbl>   <bch:tm>
1 no_warnings     833.6µs  1.06ms     832.     78.9KB     4.23   393     2      472ms
2 avoid_warnings    1.4ms  2.13ms     418.     73.2KB     6.46   194     3      464ms
3 warnings         53.9ms 56.37ms      17.8      64KB     5.08     7     2      394ms
# … with 4 more variables: result <list>, memory <list>, time <list>, gc <list>

plot(res, type = "boxplot")
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding, they will slow it down a bit, although it may be slightly more than marginal at most. However, if you don't need to use the info from the warnings, I suggest avoiding warnings, using something like suppressWarnings()

Answer (score 0):

They shouldn't have any meaningful effect on performance, unless there are millions of them, true, BUT: what I discovered, to my surprise, is that under certain conditions, warnings generated by `lifecycle::deprecate_warn` can make the code A LOT slower. Even if there are one or two of them.

This happened to me consistently when I had my ShinyApp started from RStudio, and it seemed to be specific to the case when the app is opened in the tab next to RStudio's.

by the way, has anyone had the same? Any ideas why it happens?